# How to find if a JSON object contains numbers and return them?

Tags: javascript, json

Lets say I have a [json](/questions/tagged/json)object and this is coming from a random `dataset` dynamically. I would like to search through the [json](/questions/tagged/json)and do some manipulation on the number values of that [json](/questions/tagged/json)object if there are any. I could loop through the `Object` by using a simple for..of and get the whole key but I am not sure how to go through every key value pair in the object and return the numbers. The following gives an example:

```
var obj = {
  "a0": {
    "count": 41,
    "name": "Park",

  },
  "a1": {
    "count": 52,
    "name": "Greg",

  },

  "a2": {
    "count": 150,
    "name": "Sylvain",

  },
  "a3": {
    "count": 276,
    "name": "Macho",

  },
  "a4": {
    "count": 36,
    "name": "Mariam",

  },
  "a5": {
    "count": 39,
    "name": "Blanca",

  }

}
```

I can loop through it as follows:

```
for (let i of Object.keys(obj)) {
  console.log(obj[i]);
}
```

I couldn't find any other properties on the `Object` other than `hasOwnProperty` and `keys` which could actually give me the values. I could simply access the values of the count by doing `obj[i].count`, but I wouldn't know if it has count. I am looking for a generic way to get the values and check for its type and return them as an array or do some manipulation with the number values.

Edit: I am looking to extract the properties which have numeric values in the object.

Could any one help me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to extract the numbers and work on them, or work on the numbers in place?

Comment: extract and send them to a function later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), and iterate the array of keys with [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). In the map use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get just the properties that has numeric values:

to create an array of numbers:

```js
const obj = {"a0":{"count":41, "demo": 15, "name":"Park"},"a1":{"count":52, "demo": 53, "name":"Greg"},"a2":{"count":150,"name":"Sylvain"},"a3":{"count":276,"name":"Macho"},"a4":{"count":36,"name":"Mariam"},"a5":{"count":39,"name":"Blanca"}};

const result = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
  const o = obj[key];
  
  return Object.keys(o).reduce((r, k) => typeof o[k] === 'number' ?
    Object.assign(r, { [k]: o[k] }) : r , {});
});

console.log(result);
```

And you can shorten it a bit by using [Object.value()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), and [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) if they are supported by the target browser:

```js
const obj = {"a0":{"count":41, "demo": 15, "name":"Park"},"a1":{"count":52, "demo": 53, "name":"Greg"},"a2":{"count":150,"name":"Sylvain"},"a3":{"count":276,"name":"Macho"},"a4":{"count":36,"name":"Mariam"},"a5":{"count":39,"name":"Blanca"}};

const result = Object.values(obj).map((o) =>
  Object.entries(o).reduce((r, [k, v]) => typeof v === 'number' ?
    Object.assign(r, { [k]: v }) : r , {})
);

console.log(result);
```

If you can use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), you can use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove properties which value is not a number, and then convert back to an object using `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const obj = {"a0":{"count":41, "demo": 15, "name":"Park"},"a1":{"count":52, "demo": 53, "name":"Greg"},"a2":{"count":150,"name":"Sylvain"},"a3":{"count":276,"name":"Macho"},"a4":{"count":36,"name":"Mariam"},"a5":{"count":39,"name":"Blanca"}};

const result = Object.values(obj)
  .map((o) => Object.fromEntries(
    Object
      .entries(o)
      .filter(([,v]) => typeof v === 'number')
  ))

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I love this answer. But the JSON object doesn't contain the count property. It can be anything like id or any other property which has the values as numbers. In that case how could I write a generic function?

Comment: And you want an object with all numeric properties? If so, please update the question accordingly.

Comment: Yes. Updated it.

Comment: Sorry to bug you again and for sounding dumb. I am learning JS and not a JS pro. Now, I see that we have the properties associated with the numeric values which is awesome. How can I just push the numeric values into the array instead of assigning them to an object ? I tried array.push(o[k]) and that gives me the indexes, how could I get the values ? :)

Comment: I have accepted your answer. Thanks a ton. But could you please answer my question above :)

Comment: @Tums - if you refer to this question - *In that case how could I write a generic function?*. This is a generic function, it will collect all numeric properties - see the `demo` property that exists only on some objects.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159185/discussion-between-tums-and-ori-drori).

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {"a0":{"count":41,"name":"Park"},"a1":{"count":52,"name":"Greg"},"a2":{"count":150,"name":"Sylvain"},"a3":{"count":276,"name":"Macho"},"a4":{"count":36,"name":"Mariam"},"a5":{"count":39,"name":"Blanca"}};

var newArray = [];
for (var key in obj) {
newArray.push(obj[key].count)
}
console.log(newArray);
```