# How to iterate through a JSON Object with nested properties, manipulate and return a new object?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object with nested properties as follows:

```
var obj = {

 "a0": {
    "count": 41,
    "name": "Park",
    "new": {
      "id": 35,
      "registerid": 46
     }
  },

  "a1": {
    "count": 52,
    "name": "Greg",
    "old": {
      "id": 38,
      "registerid": 49
     }
  },

  "a2": {
    "count": 150,
    "name": "Sylvain",

  }

}
```

I would like to iterate through this whole object and find the properties which have numeric values and replace them with a computed value, and return a new object.

So, if I pass in the above JSON object, I would like to return it back as:

```
result = {

     "a0": {
        "count": 411.067,
        "name": "Park",
        "new": {
          "id": 351.067,
          "registerid": 461.067
         }
      },

      "a1": {
        "count": 521.067,
        "name": "Greg",
        "old": {
          "id": 381.067,
          "registerid": 491.067
         }
      },

      "a2": {
        "count": 150.067,
        "name": "Sylvain"
      }

    }
```

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47337991/how-to-find-if-a-json-object-contains-numbers-and-return-them) which I asked previously and has a fabulous answer but it doesn't handle the nested case and it doesn't return the whole object with the replacements but does return a filtered object with numerical object properties.

I tried using the forEach on the Object.keys() and calling the map inside it, but seems like I am losing the variable scope inside the callback function.

```
let result = Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key, index) {
  Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
    let o = obj[key];
    console.log("Object is:", o);  
    return Object.keys(o).reduce((r, k) => typeof o[k] === 'number' ? Object.assign(r, { [k]:precise(o[k], 5) }) : r , {});
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Could anyone please help me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: Will it only be, at most, doubly nest like your example?

Comment: `I have a JSON object` - no, you have a javascript object, you don't have JSON at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a recursive call:

```
function process(obj) {
  let result = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
      if(typeof obj[k] === 'number') {
        result[k] = obj[k] += 0.067; // calculate you numeric properties here!
      }
      else if(typeof obj[k] === 'object') {
        result[k] = process(obj[k]); // a recursive call for nested objects
      }
      else {
        result[k] = obj[k]; // just pass an orginal value
      }
    }
  );
  return result;
}

let result = process(obj); // here the obj is the initial data object
```

I also created [Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ms88Rn?p=preview).

Comment: I suppose `obj[k] += 0.067` is technically what the author asked ("find the properties which have numeric values and replace them with a computed value, and return a new object"), but is that what they really wanted?

Comment: @vox I added comments to make the procedure more sense. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a ton!